# ADO.Net connection pooling and session affinity

Tags: mysql, ado.net

Recently I've run into the following problem. I need to execute several db statements, each of which is using its own IDbConnection object:

```cs
using (IDbConnection connection = _dbFactory.GetConnection())
{
// statement 1
}
...
using (IDbConnection connection = _dbFactory.GetConnection())
{
// statement 2
}
...
using (IDbConnection connection = _dbFactory.GetConnection())
{
// statement 3
}
```

The requirement is that all statements should be executed within the same session since there are session-dependent statements e.g. `get_lock()/release_lock()`, `set XXX` etc.

Currently, there's a problem if there is more than one connection in the ADO.net pool because each `GetConnection()` call would return random connection.

I think this can be solved by using a separate connection pool set up specifically for this task (by using a different connection string with `MaxPoolSize = 1` or something).

Will that be sufficient to guarantee the same session between `GetConnection()` calls?

Comment: you are looking for transactions. You start a transaction and then make your queries in that transaction

Comment: @nbk Transactions won't work for me, because they have a 10-minute timeout (by default) which is not enough to complete all the statements.

Comment: @MykolaKlymyuk Increase the transaction timeout.

Comment: Did you try besides increasing timeouts a stored procedure? Else without knowing database design, you have optimize your sql statements and optimize your indexing, sometimes it helps to change the database engine. after that all only increasing computing power helps